# difference between .fit() and .cross_validate() - python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, scoring

I have a dataframe of four numeric columns and they are `X1, X2, X3, Y`. I split it in 80% train and 20% test. There is no `nan` in the whole dataframe and now I need to create the model and evaluate it (I built this based on this [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/startupsci/titanic-data-science-solutions)):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
predictor_cols = ["X1","X2","X3"]
train_X = train[predictor_cols]
my_model = RandomForestRegressor()
my_model.fit(train_X, train_Y)

test_X = test[predictor_cols]
test_Y = test["Y"]  # the dependent variable is numeric
pred_test_Y = my_model.predict(test_X)

acc_rf = round(my_model.score(train_X, train_Y) * 100, 2)
acc_rf
```

I'm struggling with `my_model.fit()` as I can't find the documentation about it, but I know that it trains the model with `RandomForestRegressor()`. However, I have a few questions:

1) How `my_model.fit()` is training the model? Does it use cross-validation to increase the performance? If it does which scoring method uses to evaluate the cross-validation?

1.2) If `my_model.fit()` doesn't use cross-validation, how does it train the model at all?

1.3) If `my_model.fit()` doesn't use cross-validation, how can I use RandomForestRegressor() technique with cross-validation being able to choose the scoring method?

2) It's supposed the line below evaluate the prediction, but it doesn't (as the prediction is in the variable `pred_test_Y`, and I got a 98% accuracy with this line of code (it's accuracy at all?). I mean, what does this line?

```
acc_rf = round(my_model.score(train_X, train_Y) * 100, 2)
```

Comment: Not sure about what you want to ask. `fit()` in all sklearn estimators work on the data passed to it, to learn (train) about it. For `RandomForestRegressos, `fit()` will build multiple decision trees on different parts of data. DecisionTrees will in turn be built after find the best splitting points in the data (according to defined criteria).  Explain more about what you mean by your `1.2` point

Comment: In `1.3` what do you mean by "`being able to choose the scoring method`"? For all regressors in scikit-learn, `.score()` will calculate R-squared value (Goodness of fit) on the passed data, not `accuracy` as in traditional sense.

Comment: for 1.3 I mean being able to choose among r^2, Mean Squared Error, and other regression scores for a given ML technique. @VivekKumar I know that .fit() trains the model, but you can also train+validate with cross-validation (that's how cross-validation works I have understood). So I know now that my_model.fit() trains the model with RandomForestRegression but I don't understand how that model achieves the best performance with RandomForestRegression. I'm guessing it uses some kind of score?

Comment: It does not use any cross-validation by itself. It does not achieve the best performance by itself. In `fit()` you give it some data, it uses some inbuilt algorithm  (based on the parameters you set when initializing the estimator) to learn patterns in that data. It may and may not give you the best performance.